# VSTS connection with SOAPui via ReSTapi

Tags: rest, azure-devops, soapui, azure-devops-rest-api

I am trying to make connection to Azure VSTS with SOAPui through vsts rest api's, but the response I am getting is: HTTP/1.1 203 Non-Authoritative information 
Though when I hit the same request from POSTMAN it's giving successful response for every operation(Get, Post, Delete).
As I have a framework for API automation in SOAPUI I need to have this connection to post the test results in VSTS against respective test case.
Any idea how to resolve this would be much appreciated!! 
Thanks

Comment: Please show what you tried so far, it would make it easier to answer your question.

Comment: I have tried to authenticate using basic authentication and OAUTH 2.0 and both are giving the same results:

Comment: I have tried to authenticate using basic authentication and OAUTH 2.0 and both are giving the same results: Receiving response: HTTP/1.1 200 Connection Established ending request: POST /_signin?realm=dev.azure.com&reply_to=https%3A%2F%2Fdev.azure.com%2Fitron%2F_apis%2Fprojects%2FRnD%2F&redirect=1&aadinmsa=true&hid=f13f9640-8c1f-4fc9-880a-d32afafdefba&context=eyJodCI6MiwiaGlkIjoiNGNiYTlhNzAtMjg1NC00ODY4LWE1OTQtNWRkZDJhMDIzOTA5IiwicXMiOnt9LCJyciI6IiIsInZoIjoiIiwiY3YiOiIiLCJjcyI6IiJ90#ctx=eyJTaWduSW5Db29raWVEb21haW5zIjpbImh0dHBzOi8vbG9naW4ub

Comment: Below is the xml output:<meta content="HTML Tidy for Java (vers. 27 Sep 2004), see www.w3.org" name="generator"/>
      <title>Azure DevOps Services | Sign In</title>
      <meta content="IE=11; IE=10; IE=9; IE=8" http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible"/>
      <link href="/favicon.ico" rel="SHORTCUT ICON"/>
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="/_static/tfs/M144_20181207.18/_cssbundles/Default/vss-bundle-commoncss-vzeF08Mjegl5n-ljmBHBTxMi4J-enCRh2z3493w0rop8=" data-includedstyles="jQueryUI-Modified;Core;Splitter;PivotView" data-highcontrast="/_static/tfs/M144_20181207.18/_cssbundles/HighContrast/vss-

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is due to the incorrect authentication headers (Authorization header) that you send in the request. I have experienced this issue when you are trying to send empty username in **SoapUI** - Basic Authorization tab.

This can be handled by generating the header offline (using some online utilities - https://www.blitter.se/utils/basic-authentication-header-generator/) and sending in a separate header like below,

```
Authorization: Basic Onl1eWl1eWl5aXlpeWl5aXk=
```

Hope this helps.